# What does the checkbox "link to content" do?

Tags: theming

I am creating some custom content but have not got round to creating the views yet. When looking at the layout tab I see this
[image: Link to content]

What content does this refers to? All my Plain text fields have this checkbox, but none of the others.

Comment: Have you simply tried it out? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are in display settings of a content type and these are the fields it has. *Link to content* in this context means that when this field is displayed it will link back to the parent node.   It will be displayed as link similar to this

```html
<label>Surname</label><a href="/node/2">This surname</a>
```

where the `/node/2` would be the url of the node you are actually viewing

NOTE: if you enable this on the default content type view mode it will not make much sense as it will link on the page you are currently on (`node/2`).  This makes sense for example when the node is displayed as part of a view and in that case if clicking on the link will take you to the full node.